# junit test with mockito using argumentCaptor

Tags: junit, mockito

I am learning to write test cases in junit using mockito. Can anyone please explain how to write junit test using ArgumentCaptor for a method like this ?

```
public int mtd(A a){
int value=dao.getValues(a);
return value;
}
```

My junit test case look like this

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

  @Mock
  private InternDAO internDAO;

  @Mock
  InternServiceImpl service;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    service = new InternServiceImpl();
  }
  @Test
  public void test() throws DataServiceException, BusinessServiceException {

      Intern intern=new Intern();
  intern.setStartDate(new Date());
    intern.setEndDate(new Date());
    Mockito.when(service.doSignedUpCount(intern)).thenReturn(2);
    int val=service.doSignedUpCount(intern);
 Assert.assertEquals(val, 2);

  }

}
```

It i throwing nullpointer exception

Comment: Please show what you have already tried? If you don't know where to start take a look at the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mockito/2055/introduction-to-mockito/16192/verifying-arguments-with-argumentcaptor#t=201608120856397601709

Answer (score 0):

First of all Thanks **@noscreenname** for helping me.
I got NullPointerException cause i didn't set internDAO object value.